# Rich calendar component for Swing application

Tags: java, swing, calendar

My company is adding some rich calendar functionality to our Swing application.  We want it to work like Outlook's calendar.  Here are some of our requirments:

- Views for day, week, and month
- The ability to specify calendar items down to the minute level
- The ability to drag and drop calendar elements into different slots
- Editing of calendar details directly on the calendar
- Printing support
- Customizable look and feel
- 508 compliance support would be a big plus

At the moment, we're planning on going with [MiG Calendar](http://migcalendar.com/), but I was wondering if anyone had any experience with other Swing components with similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just sticking with MiG Calendar.  Another team took over the work on this feature, so I can't say first hand how well it worked.  However, I got the impression that it got the job done.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it personally (yet), but I know others who have been satisfied with this: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/index.html

Comment: I am currently using this with great success.

Comment: I clarified our requirements in the question, we need something that can show calendar items down to the minute level.