# Overlay JButton/s with rounded rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a system which contains a 2D array of `JButtons`. Each button is a 30 minute appointment for a booking system. I can set a simple `ImageIcon` over the `JButton` for a 30 min appointment but how would I go about and span a `ImageIcon` over two buttons to represent a one hour long appointment?

As you can see from my mockup below

[image: As seen in my mockup system]

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [mcve] and an image of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You might look for a calendar component, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1828302/230513).